# How to embed a UIImageView into a UIScrollView in iOS using Xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview, xcode4.5

I am trying to learn how to use the UIScrollView and I am hitting a simple roadblock it seems.

I am able to create an empty UIScrollView build and run and it works.  I then try to add an image and I can get the image to show but I am unable to scroll.

Here is the code contents of my viewcontroller.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

In viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I added the UIImageView via the interface builder.  It is embedded within the scroll view.  The size of the image is also greater than the scroll view.  Here is the screenshot:

[image]

When I build and run I get a full screen view of a part of the image but cannot scroll to see the rest.  Any clue as to why I cannot scroll to see the rest of the image?

Comment: the scroll view only can be scrolled if its contentsize is bigger than   its frame size, try to set your scrollview's contentsize same as your image view's framesize.

Comment: Also x=-28 & y=-134 of imageview is getting out of scrollview's bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `contentSize` should be the size of your `UIImageView`. In this case, you should do this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(427, 777)];
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  That did the trick.  I was mistakenly thinking this line set the frame size of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to use "ContentSize" property of the scrollview.

You can have below syntex:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(<width>, <height>)];
```

Cheers.